# Как можно получить client ID для youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

Я зарегистрирован на console.cloud.google.com 
Можно стрелочным образом таким способом сказать куда нажимать куда зайти/перейти 
`нажать сюда -> потом сюда -> откроется это -> и т.д.` ?
Просто дизайн изменился а все видео на показывают это на старом дизайне.
Долго мучаюсь не могу получить CLIENT ID для Youtube API. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотел в комментарии отправить, не могу.
Generating your API Key:

```
Goto - https://console.developers.google.com
Create a new project
Select "APIs & auth"
Select "APIs"
Select "Youtube Data API v3" and enable it
Select "Credentials"
Create new Key, select browser and then press create (don't enter anything in the text box)
```

Comment: Выглядит как ответ, только, пожалуйста, помните что у нас SO на русском, переведите ответ.